# Android setText work but button doesn't update

Tags: android

I want to change the text on a button when onResume() is called, (the setText its working because if I do a Toast it shows me the text I want but the button has the old string).

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(ban == 0) {
        reDraw();
        fillInfo();

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("layoutRequestData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        getFlagSendBill = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("flagSendBill", false);//comenzar servicio

        if(getFlagSendBill == true) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.request,null);
            buttonBService = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
            //buttonBService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
            buttonBService.setText("Ver Recibo");

            Toast.makeText(this,"LALALA" + buttonBService.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
           // buttonBService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
            //buttonBService.setText("Comenzar Servicio");
        }
    }
}
```

My buttonBService and my getFlagSendBill are public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the hole button, take a look at the Activity lifecycle, 
the good practice is that you initialize the button in the `onCreate` method, then assign any value in the `onResume`, the same applies to the view....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Why are you inflating a new layout?  You should be changing the text on the existing layout.  By inflating a new one and not setting it as the context view you're changing the text on a button that isn't ever on screen.

Comment: Because if I don't do that the findViewById throws me a nullpointerException, so how could I find the Button from another layout?

Comment: This is an Activity, right?  Use findViewById on the Activity object, it will do it on the view that was set via setContentView.

Comment: if I do this:   if(getFlagSendBill == true) {
                
                buttonBService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
                //buttonBService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonBeginService);
                buttonBService.setText("Ver Recibo");

                Toast.makeText(this,"LALALA" + buttonBService.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } it throws me  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Comment: Also, this isn't necessarily wrong, but its considered good practice that any views you will use elsewhere in your activity you get a reference to in onCreate and save in a member variable of the Activity, rather than repeatedly query for it by findViewById.  This is because findViewById does a linear search over the entire layout, its best to do this only once per view.